# Issues with biber on Mac

Tags: installing, biber

I am running Mac OS Mojave, and want to use `biblatex` with `biber`.

I am not 100% sure, but I think I initially installed the 'lite' version of tex-live so that I have to manually install various packages (because of storage limitations), `biber` was thus not installed by default.

I downloaded `biber` from [here](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/), but running it gives the error:

```
Can't locate PAR.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PAR module)
```

I then did `cpan install PAR`, which gives:

```
Reading '/Users/user/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 02 Jan 2019 10:41:03 GMT
PAR is up to date (1.015).
```

But I still get the same error from running biber as shown above.

Any idea why I would be getting this error?

Comment: Don't install Biber from Sourceforge unless you absolutely have to. If you installed TeX live or Mac TeX from TUG you should be able to run `tlmgr` or the *TeX Live Utility* to install Biber.

Comment: Thanks, `tlmgr install biber` worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should always be the last resort to install Biber (or `biblatex`) from Sourceforge. You usually get better results and into less trouble when you install packages via your TeX distribution.

With MacTeX/TeX live you can either say

```
tlmgr install biber
```

in the command line or use the GUI *TeX Live Utility*.

Comment: Ran this but still getting the same error as OP re. can't find PAR.pm.  Using MacTeX & homebrew.